# Use underscorejs to create an object that counts duplicates

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'd like to take an array and transform it into an object that contains the number of duplicates for each word.

For example:

```
// original array
var arr = ['cat','dog','dog','dog','cat','bird','mouse'];

// transform into 
{
    'cat'  : 2,
    'dog'  : 3,
    'bird' : 1,
    'mouse': 1
}
```

I'm trying to find the appropriate underscore method that would do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [countBy](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy)

```
console.log(_.countBy(arr));
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/qonesa/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Anything you want, Underscore's got it, apparently haha. Brilliant.